# angularjs custom filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to return unique values from a JSON response via a custom filter.

data:

```
[
{
    "SHFUserID": "400",
    "AlertID": "12",
    "TickerID": "4512",
    "Ticker": "GOOG",
    "Active": "1",
    "Status": "2"
},
{
    "SHFUserID": "400",
    "AlertID": null,
    "TickerID": "4512",
    "Ticker": "GOOG",
    "Active": null,
    "Status": null
},
{
    "SHFUserID": "400",
    "AlertID": null,
    "TickerID": "10190",
    "Ticker": "IBM",
    "Active": null,
    "Status": null
}
]
```

filter:

```
.filter('uniqueTickers', function() {
return function(tickers) {
    var tags = {};
    angular.forEach(tickers, function(obj) {

      if(!(obj.Ticker in tags)){
        tags[obj.Ticker] = {id: obj.TickerID, name:obj.Ticker}

        if(!tags[obj.Ticker].pending){
          tags[obj.Ticker].pending = 0;
        }
        if(!tags[obj.Ticker].settled){
          tags[obj.Ticker].settled = 0;
        }
        if(!tags[obj.Ticker].order){
          tags[obj.Ticker].order = 3;
        }
      }
  if(obj.Status === "1"){
    tags[obj.Ticker].pending = 1;
    if(tags[obj.Ticker].order > 2){
      tags[obj.Ticker].order = 2;
    }
  }
  if(obj.Status === "2"){
    tags[obj.Ticker].settled = 1;
    if(tags[obj.Ticker].order > 1){
      tags[obj.Ticker].order = 1;
    }
  };
    });
return tags;
};
```

html:

```
 Search: <input ng-model="query">
  Sort by:
  <select ng-model="orderProp">
    <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
    <option value="order">Alert Status</option>
  </select>
  <ul class="tickerList">
    <li ng-repeat="ticker in tickers | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp | uniqueTickers">
      <a href="#/ticker/{{ticker.id}}">{{ticker.name}}</a>
      <p>{{ticker}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

but the result looks like:

```
GOOG
{"id":"4512","name":"GOOG","pending":0,"settled":0,"order":3}

IBM
{"id":"10190","name":"IBM","pending":0,"settled":0,"order":3}
```

instead of:

```
GOOG
{"id":"4512","name":"GOOG","pending":0,"settled":1,"order":1}

IBM
{"id":"10190","name":"IBM","pending":0,"settled":0,"order":3}
```

The goal is to keep the result set unique but set "pending" or "settled" to true if any of the records for that ticker are pending or settled.

Comment: I'm not seeing the logic that enforces uniqueness.

Comment: i am overriding the object[key] (tags[obj.Ticker]) so that duplicate tickers should act on the same record. At least that is what I assume is happening?

Comment: Ok, but from your results it looks like the second GOOG is overwriting the first GOOG. How do you tell which one you want?

Comment: yeah i needed to add a !("key" in obj) check before overriding the instance

Comment: i updated the post to reflect the change. if you want to post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I added an answer; we should probably revert your last edit for clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion, the answer was to avoid overwiting existing data by adding a check around the first section of logic like this:

```
if(!(obj.Ticker in tags)){
    tags[obj.Ticker] = {id: obj.TickerID, name:obj.Ticker};

    if(!tags[obj.Ticker].pending){
      tags[obj.Ticker].pending = 0;
    }
    if(!tags[obj.Ticker].settled){
      tags[obj.Ticker].settled = 0;
    }
    if(!tags[obj.Ticker].order){
      tags[obj.Ticker].order = 3;
    }
}
```